# matplotlib: legend does not inherit node_color from networkx graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am running matplotlib v1.4.3 with Python 2.7 on Windows 7.  When I generate a graph using networkx, the node colors passed through the node_color parameter are not being inherited by the legend.  The legend's circles are the default blue color.  The following code is a test case to show the issue.  I am a new user to SO and not able to post images, but you can copy/paste the code to see the problem.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# define nodes, node types, and color range
np.random.seed(10000)
nodes = list('abcdefghijkl')
nodeTypes = ['foo','bar','baz']
nodeColors = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]

# assign each node a type and color via a dictionaries
nodeTypeDict = dict(zip(nodeTypes, [nodes[:4],nodes[4:8],nodes[8:]]))
nodeColorDict = dict(zip(nodeTypes, nodeColors))
nodePos = dict(zip(nodes,[(np.random.random(),np.random.random()) 
                                        for i in range(len(nodes))]))

# generate the graph
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(nodes)

# create image canvas and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(6,6))

# iterate each nodetype, changing colors and labels of the nodes
for nt in nodeTypes:
    # choose nodes and color for each iteration
    nlist = nodeTypeDict[nt]
    ncolor = [nodeColorDict[nt]]*len(nlist)
    # draw the graph
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, 
                           pos=nodePos,
                           nodelist=nlist,
                           ax=ax, 
                           cmap=plt.cm.brg, 
                           vmin=0.0,
                           vmax=1.0,
                           node_color=ncolor,
                           label=nt)  # the label for each iteration is 
                                      # the node type

# here is the problem.  The legend does not inherit the colors.
ax.legend(scatterpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that works.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# define nodes, node types, and color range
np.random.seed(10000)
nodes = list('abcdefghijkl')
nodeTypes = ['foo','bar','baz']
nodeColors = ['r', 'b', 'k']

# assign each node a type and color via a dictionaries
nodeTypeDict = dict(zip(nodeTypes, [nodes[:4],nodes[4:8],nodes[8:]]))
nodeColorDict = dict(zip(nodeTypes, nodeColors))
nodePos = dict(zip(nodes,[(np.random.random(),np.random.random()) 
                                        for i in range(len(nodes))]))

# generate the graph
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(nodes)

# create image canvas and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(6,6))

# iterate each nodetype, changing colors and labels of the nodes
for nt in nodeTypes:
    # choose nodes and color for each iteration
    nlist = nodeTypeDict[nt]
    ncolor = nodeColorDict[nt]
    print ncolor
    # draw the graph
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, 
                           pos=nodePos,
                           nodelist=nlist,
                           ax=ax, 
                           node_color=ncolor,
                           label=nt)  # the label for each iteration is 
                                      # the node type

# here is the problem.  The legend does not inherit the colors.
ax.legend(scatterpoints=1)
plt.savefig('tmp.png')
```

[image]

I thought I had a quick explanation of what was wrong, but I don't really.  First - if you're making all the colors the same for a particular command, there's no need to send a list of colors to the `draw_networkx_nodes`.  Just change that to a single color.  I thought that would fix it, but then I ran into trouble with the cmap.  I then explicitly stated what color to use, and the problem was fixed.

So - what I've got works, and it appears to be that when it draws the legend it doesn't get the right color as encoded by the color map.  I recommend determining the color before the call to `draw_networkx_nodes` and just sending the color.

Comment: Thanks.  This helped alot.  It looks like the color_node only wants RGB and not RGBa from the cmap to be able to pass to the legend.  I added
`nodeColorsIndex = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]` and 
`nodeColors = [colmap(nci)[0:3] for nci in nodeColorsIndex]`
and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yep - I was just playing with it, and figured out that the problem was it wanted a length 3.  I was still having a bit of trouble figuring out how to get it to respect the vmin and vmax arguments.  I'll leave it for now if it's working for you.